# iOS: how to determine if a file is a bundle resource (included in IPA)

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager

I'm building a framework, and need to differentiate between a file that is a bundle resource (included in the App Store IPA / static file defined at development time) and a file that the app creates (downloads and saves, or just otherwise writes to a file in application support, temp, or any other writeable location).

I want to do this because the SDK is free to use with a local config file, but using a cloud-based config that updates without shipping an app update is a paid feature.

I've tried a few ways, but I've quickly found ways to defeat my own checks.

- Check file permissions: but the app can just change any file to read only permissions
- Check the file exists in a bundle: but the temp directory (and probably others) are in the main bundle

Any authoritative way to check a file is a bundle resource included in the app release, and not just any old file?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are writing a framework, why do you need such a check? Why wouldn't your framework only access a bundled (read-only) config file in its "free" mode and only access a different, writable configuration file somewhere within the app's sandbox when in "paid" mode?

Comment: The framework consumer provides the file path to their config. It's not built into the framework (would vary app to app). They are allowed their own config, even in free, but updating the config between releases (download file to tmp for example) is what I want to detect.

Comment: So is their own config, for the free version, required to be bundled as part of their app and your framework looks for it in the app's bundle? And for the paid version, how does your framework know where to look for it? I still don't see what the issue is. If you know to access the file in the app bundle for the free version and you know to look outside the bundle for the paid version, what's the issue?

Comment: They are providing a path. They need to be able to provide a custom file (each app will have its own config). It's trivial for them to provide a path/name, and for the framework to access it. The ask here is how the framework can tell this path is a static resource, and not just a file the app downloaded at saved to that path dynamically. They could trivially recreate the paid plan's features (cloud update). As an app dev tying to bypass check, I can easily save a file into a path in the bundle, and pass the framework that path. From the FW side I can't find a secure way to tell the difference

Comment: Extra data point: might work fine by checking if the file is a subdirectory of mainBundle.bundleURL. I think writing tests were catching me up. In framework unit tests, the tmp directory is a subdirectory of the test bundle path, but not when running the app itself. Will need to explore more. But a more authoritative property for "is static" in some way would be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

After some testing, this is easier than I thought.

```
NSString *mainBundlePath = NSBundle.mainBundle.bundleURL.absoluteString;
return [pathToCheck hasPrefix:mainBundlePath];
```

The issue was that testing it is nearly impossible. When test cases are running, the tmp, application support, caches, and documents directories all appear inside the test bundle. In real apps running outside of tests, these directories are outside of that bundle.